# How can I test randomly ordered data from Postgres?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, unit-testing, random, minitest

I'm writing a REST API that returns products in JSON from a Postgres database.

I have written integration tests to test which products are returned and this works fine. A requirement has just been introduced to randomly order the products returned.

I've changed my tests to not rely on the order the results come back in. My problem is testing the new random requirement.

I plan on implementing this in the database with Postgres' `RANDOM()` keyword. If I was doing this "in code" I could stub the random code generator to always be the same value, but I'm not sure what to do in the database.

How can I test that my new random requirement is working?

Comment: Does it have to be cryptographically secure randomness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way of doing what I need.

You can [set the seed value for Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) using `SETSEED()`.

If you set the seed before the you execute the query that uses `RANDOM()`, the results will come back in the same order every time.

```
SELECT SETSEED(0.5);

SELECT id, title FROM products ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2;
```

The seed value is reset after the `SELECT` query.

To test that the data comes back random we can change the seed value.

I don't want to test if Postgres' `RANDOM()` works, but that my code that uses it does.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on your definition of *randomness*. As a first try you could issue the same request twice and make sure that the same result set is returned but in a different order. This of course assumes that your test data will not page or some such, but if it does your test will of course be more difficult, as you would probably have to retrieve all pages in order to verify anything.

On second thoughts paging would probably complicate the whole request, as it would require having the *same* randomness across several pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't this will work though. If I issue two requests there is no guarantee that results will come back in different orders. They may come back in the same order twice.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if you want to test randomness, you should find a query that return few results - 2 would be the ideal number.

You then run the query a big number of times and count the occurences of the different ordering possibilities. The number must not reach same value, but the frequencies should converge toward 1/n, where n is the number of orderings. But in fact, you do not want the quality of the random generator, all you need is to be sure that you correctly use it. So you should only test that you get one of each possibility for a correct number of tests.

I would use 100 run if n <= 10 and n<sup>2</sup> if n > 10. For n = 10 and 100 runs the probability of having one possibility off is less than 3e-5. So run the test once, and run it again if it fails, and it should be enough. Of course, if you want to reduce the risk of false detection simply augment the number of runs ... but tests will be longer ...

Comment: This sounds very complex. I'm not sure the test is worth the complexity.

Comment: @jordelver : It is easy to prove data is ordered it is hard to prove you have a random order ...

Comment: Yes, hence my question in the first place :)